# Javascript Add Row to HTML Table & Increment ID

Tags: javascript, html

This is my first post on this site so hopefully you will go easy on me. I'm trying to create an HTML / PHP form and use a small piece of Javascript to add additional rows to a table when a button is clicked and increment the ID for the two fields.

The button works in adding the rows however it doesn't seem to increment the ID, just use the same ID as the previous row. Hopefully someone could help?

```js
$(window).load(function(){
        var table = $('#productanddates')[0];

    var newIDSuffix = 2;
    $(table).delegate('#button2', 'click', function () {
        var thisRow = $(this).closest('tr')[0];

        var cloned = $(thisRow).clone();
        cloned.find('input, select').each(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            id = id.substring(0, id.length - 1) + newIDSuffix;
            $(this).attr('id', id);
        });

        cloned.insertAfter(thisRow).find('input:date').val('');

        newIDSuffix++;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="blue-bar ta-l">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Submit Your Insurance Renewal Date(s)</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="grey-bar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="rounded-box">
            <div>
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" autocomplete="off" required />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="name">Renewal Dates</label>
            </div>
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" id="productanddates" class="border">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <select name="insurance_type1" id="insurance_type1">
                                <option></option>
                                <option>Car</option>
                                <option>Home</option>
                                <option>Van</option>
                                <option>Business</option>
                                <option>GAP</option>
                                <option>Travel</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="date" name="renewal_date1" id="renewal_date1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" name="button2" id="button2" value="+" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
            <div>
                <label for="telephone_number">Contact Number</label>
                <input type="tel" id="telephone_number" name="telephone_number" pattern="\d{11}" autocomplete="off" required />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" autocomplete="off" required />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: for dynamic html like this it is better to learn how to use classes and DOM traverses instead of worrying about needing ID's at all. Show the code that is dependent on ID's

Comment: It seems to work in this jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/g7116c49/ by changing `.find('input:date')` to `.find('input.date')` and adding `class="date"` to your date input.

Comment: Have you tried to put a declaration of `newIDSuffix` in Global JavaScript instead of in the function `$(window).load`?

Comment: @charlietfl - I wouldn't discourage people using `id` attributes in the form elements.  Not only is it a best practice to have a label tied to each input by matching the labels `for` attribute to the inputs `id`, it is absolutely essential for any kind of accessability support (i.e., for screen readers).

Comment: @talemyn point taken about accessibility, but in general people learning about working with the DOM tend to over rely on ID as the best way to access an element when it can actually lead to extra complications

Comment: @charlietfl - absolutely a fair point . . . it's all about learning to use the right attributes for the right reasons.   :)

Comment: Since you're using a newer version of jQuery, I recommend using `.on()` instead of `.delegate()`.  Per the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) - *As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gone ahead an taken a stab at a cleaner version of what I think that you are trying to accomplish.  I'll walk through the major updates:

1. **Updated the button `id` and `name` from "button2" to "button1"** - I assumed that you would want to keep the indices in sync across the inputs in each row.
2. **Changing `$(window).load(function() {` to `$("document").ready(function() {`** - While either will work, the former will wait until all images have finished loading, while the latter while fire once the DOM has completed building.  Unless you REALLY want the images to load first, I'd recommend `$("document").ready()`, for faster triggering of the code.
3. **Removing the `[0]` references** - the primary reason to use `[0]` after a jQuery selector collection is to reference the DOM version of the selected jQuery element, in order to us a "vanilla" JavaScript method on it.  In all cases, you were re-rwapping the variables in `$(...)`, which just converted the DOM element back into a jQuery object, so that extra step was not needed.
4. **Changed the `.delegate()` method to `.on()`** - as Howard Renollet noted, that is the correct method to use for modern versions of jQuery.  Note that the "event" and "target" parameters have swapped places in `on`, from where they were in `delegate`.
5. **Changed the event target from `#button2` to `:button`** - this will make sure that all of the buttons in the new rows will also allow you to add additional rows, not just the first one.
6. **Switched the `clone` target from the clicked row to the last row in the table** - this will help keep your row numbering consistant and in ascending order.  The cloned row will always be the last one, regardless of which one was clicked, and the new row will always be placed at the end, after it.
7. **Changed the indexing to use the last row's index as the base for the new row and use a regular expression to determine it** - with the table being ordered now, you can always count on the last row to have the highest index.  By using the regular expression `/^(.+)(\d+)$/i`, you can split up the index value into "everything before the index" and "the index (i.e., on or more numbers, at the end of the value)".  Then, you simply increment the index by 1 and reattach it, for the new value.  Using the regex approach also allows you to easily adapt, it there ever get to be more than 9 rows (i.e., double-digit indices).
8. **Updated both the `id` and `name` attributes for each input** - I assumed that you would want the `id` and `name` attributes to be the same for each individual element, based on the initial row, and, you were only updating the `id` in your code, which would have caused problems when sending the data.
9. **Changed `$("input:date")` to `$("input[type='date'])`** - as Mouser pointed out, this was really the core reason why your code was failing, initially.  All of the other changes will help you avoid additional issues in the future or were simply "code quality"-related changes.

So . . . those were the major updates.  :)  Let me know if I misunderstood what you were trying to do or if you have any questions.

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
 $('#productanddates').on('click', ':button', function () {
  var lastRow = $(this).closest('table').find("tr:last-child");

  var cloned = lastRow.clone();
  cloned.find('input, select').each(function () {
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   
   var regIdMatch = /^(.+)(\d+)$/; 
   var aIdParts = id.match(regIdMatch);
   var newId = aIdParts[1] + (parseInt(aIdParts[2], 10) + 1);

   $(this).attr('id', newId);
   $(this).attr('name', newId);
  });

  cloned.find("input[type='date']").val('');
  cloned.insertAfter(lastRow);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="blue-bar ta-l">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Submit Your Insurance Renewal Date(s)</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="grey-bar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="rounded-box">
            <div>
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" autocomplete="off" required />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="name">Renewal Dates</label>
            </div>
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" id="productanddates" class="border">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <select name="insurance_type1" id="insurance_type1">
                                <option></option>
                                <option>Car</option>
                                <option>Home</option>
                                <option>Van</option>
                                <option>Business</option>
                                <option>GAP</option>
                                <option>Travel</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="date" name="renewal_date1" id="renewal_date1" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" name="button1" id="button1" value="+" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
            <div>
                <label for="telephone_number">Contact Number</label>
                <input type="tel" id="telephone_number" name="telephone_number" pattern="\d{11}" autocomplete="off" required />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" autocomplete="off" required />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: And now your going to charge him for `1 million dollars`  **\*put's pinky finger to his mouth\***

Comment: LOL . . . he gave it a good shot . . . figured that I would help him out a bit.   ;)

Comment: @talemyn you sir, are my hero. I cant thank you enough for this, it works perfectly and is exactly what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @JohnWoods - Excellent . . . happy to help.  Glad it worked for you.   :)

Answer (score 2):

```
cloned.insertAfter(thisRow).find('input:date').val('');
```

This line isn't correct. It will throw an `invalid selector` error.

You need to change it to:

```
cloned.insertAfter(thisRow).find('input[type="date"]').val('');
```

jQuery actually does support the `:INPUT-TYPE format` in selectors, but not the new HTML5 input types (yet): so using `input[type="date"]` here is the correct way for now to select an element with  an HTML5 type. Please notice the quotes around the value. If you want to select an attribute with a certain value.

A selector overview of css selectors here: [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Because this line is throwing an error your `newIDSuffix` never gets updated, because the script halts at the line before that because of the script error.

---

@[Charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl) raises a valid point about learning more about classes and DOM traversal. However that will not fix this code. Or explain why your code isn't working. Nevertheless it's a good tip.

Comment: While correct, your answer is a little misleading in the explaination.  jQuery actually does support the `:INPUT-TYPE` format in selectors, but not the new HTML5 input types (yet):  http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/form-selectors/   Had he been trying to update the button in the form, for example, `.find("input:button")` or even `.find(":button")` would have worked just fine.  While related, the css selectors and jQuery selectors do have some differences.

Comment: @talemyn, thanks for the update. Updated my answer to match your comment so it's technically correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
cloned.insertAfter(thisRow).find('input[type="date"]').val('');
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.